# Attach to a IIS Worker Process using Fiddler get a RemoteCertificateChainErrors

Tags: debugging, iis, fiddler

When I run Fiddler to capture traffic between my server and client. I get the following warning message. How can I find out which certificate is causing the problem and how to fix the error?

```
Session #30: The remote server (server.mycompany.com) presented a certificate that did not validate, due to RemoteCertificateChainErrors.

0 - A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority.


SUBJECT: CN=dev.server.mycompany.com, OU=Space, O=Company, L=NewYork, S=NY, C=US
ISSUER: CN=Space Test Authority, OU=Space, O=Company, L=NewYork, S=NY, C=US
```

Comment: The CN field is so clear and I wonder if you notice. To fix it, find out how the certificate is configured on the server side, export its CA and add to the trusted root authority on the client side. Or change the server side certificate to a valid one.

Comment: Thanks, What do you mean by CN filed is so clear. sorry I am not familiar how a certificate should look.